# select <li> that does not have <a>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Bonjour,

I would like to make sure to always have the same padding in `<li>`, but when it's a link that the padding is in the `<a>` (for large selection area).

```css
li a {
  padding: 1rem;
}

li:not(a) {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href='#'>Text</a></li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li><a href='#'>Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

- I want padding in the `<a>` when it exists and no more in the `<li>`
- And when there is no `<a>` the padding is in the `<li>`

Comment: Only with li im not sure that is possible, maybe you can add a span inside the li and give it the padding there? It will be basically the same, but when it's an `a` you can have that extra zone to click

Comment: I don't think this is possible with `css` alone, as you can't check if an element has a child using `css`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use negative margins on the `a`, and then the `a`'s padding will be in the same position as the `li`'s.

```css
li {
  padding: 1rem;
}

li a {
  margin: -1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href='#'>Text</a></li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li><a href='#'>Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why does it need the inline-block?

Comment: @AndrewBone Sorry, wasn't thinking. You're right, that is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Thanks @MrLister for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways to do this, Mr Lister's answer is sufficient but I'm opposed to using negative margins so thought I'd offer another couple of options.

**CSS Only (works in all browsers):**

In this example, I've added a span around all li contents that are not `<a>`'s. I use calc to work out a height we want each `<li>`.

There is also a CSS variable, this is just so you can change the padding in one place and can be left out if need be.

```css
:root {
  --li-padding: 1em;
}

li {
  height: calc(100% + (var(--li-padding) * 2));
  line-height: calc(100% + (var(--li-padding) * 2));
  background: tomato;
}

li>* {
  padding: 0 var(--li-padding);
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Line 1</a></li>
  <li><span>Line 2</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Line 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS Only (works in no browsers, *yet*):**

This is a proposed standard for CSS Level 4, currently, it's not in any browsers but I thought it worth mentioning just for future proofing.

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

```css
li:not(::has(> a)) {
  padding: 1em;
}

li>a {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Line 1</a></li>
  <li>Line 2</li>
  <li><a href="#">Line 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Use Javascript:**

Using javascript we can look through all the `<li>` tags and decide what we want to do depending on what they contain, here's a quick example (again I used colour to show where the `<a>` tags start).

```js
let liSelector = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (let i = 0; i < liSelector.length; i++) {
  let str = liSelector[i].innerHTML;
  if (str.includes("</a>")) {
    liSelector[i].querySelector('a').style.padding = "1em";
    liSelector[i].querySelector('a').style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
    liSelector[i].style.padding = "1em";
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  background: tomato;
}

li a {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Line 1</a></li>
  <li>Line 2</li>
  <li><a href="#">Line 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Summary:**
Mr Lister's answer should be all you need but I think it's good to have all your options as it helps understand the problem and solve other problems in the future, I hope you find this helpful

Comment: Thanks for the css 4 example !!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go in jQUery :

```js
$('li').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('a').length) {
       $(this).addClass('extrapadding');
    }
});
```

```css
.extrapadding a {
  padding: 1rem;
}

li:not(.extrapadding) {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>Text</a></li>
<li>Text</li>
<li><a href='#'>Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Providing a jQuery answer to a question which isn't tagged as such is like providing a Java answer to a HTML question - sure, it could fix the problem, but the overhead would be really unnecessary.